# Does keypress() only fire when a textfield is focused in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('body').keypress(function (e) {
        alert(e.which);
    });
});
```

This will pop up an alert when a key is pressed in Chrome but not in Firefox. However, if I create a text field and focus it, then press a key, an alert will pop up in Firefox. (Even though $('body') is still the jQuery object.)

How can I get the event to fire in Firefox even when a textfield is not focused? Is there a workaround? I will be firing an event when the Enter key is pressed anywhere on the page.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have no elements on the page, the browser might assume that the `<body>` element (or any of its descendants) doesn't have focus. Try binding your event to the document:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).keypress(function (e) {
        alert(e.which);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

@DarthJDG is right, but you should still set focus on the window if you want to listen for keypresses immidiately after page load.  in some cases browsers will leave focus on the address bar.  so add:

```
$(window).focus();
```

after setting up the keypress handler